# JQM popup not working properly on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm using JQM 1.3.1 and I have a page with several popups (popups are at the bottom of page):

```
<div data-role="page" data-title="Strategic Plans">
    <div data-role="content" id="capbPlans" data-bind="cafeLiveScroll: { callback: getMorePlans, threshold: 0.5 }">

        <!-- ko2 foreach:planGroups -->
        <section data-bind="cafeExpand: {}">
            <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>

            <!-- ko if: $root.auth.isAllowCreate() -->
            <div class="capbPlan capbInvite capbClosed" data-bind="click: function(o,e) { $(e.target).removeClass('capbClosed').find( 'textarea' ).focus(); }" title="Add new Plan">
                <textarea data-bind="value: invite, event: {keypress: createPlan}, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="Enter a name for your strategic plan" aria-label="Name" maxlength="100"></textarea>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="capbBtn capbBtnCancel" data-bind="click: function(o,e) { $(e.target).parent().parent().addClass('capbClosed').find( 'textarea' ).val('').blur(); }">Cancel</a>
                    <a href="#" class="capbBtn" data-bind="click: createPlan">Save</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko foreach: plans -->
            <div data-bind="click: $root.goPlan, attr:{ 'class': 'capbPlan capbPlanPhase' + strategyPhase.id }">
                <!-- ko if: $root.auth.isAllowCreate() -->
                <a href="#" class="copyIcon" title="Copy" data-bind="click: function(o,e){$root.selectedPlan(o);var a=$(e.target), m = $('#capbPlansMenu');$.Event(e).stopPropagation(); m.popup('open', {x: a.offset().left + m.outerWidth() / 2 + 5, y: a.offset().top + 35 })}"><div class="cafeImg capbIconMenu"></div></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>
                <p data-bind="text: description" class="desc"></p>
                <p data-bind="text: phase, attr:{ 'class': 'phase ' + phase }"></p>
                <footer>
                    <div data-bind="cafeUser: assignedTo" title="Owned by"></div>
                    <div data-bind="text: $root.i18n.format(modifiedOn, 'd')" title="Last modify"></div>
                </footer>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </section>
        <!-- /ko2 -->
        <div id="capbPlansMenu" data-role="popup" class="capbPlansMenu" data-corners="false" data-position-to="origin">
            <ul>
                <li data-bind="click: function(o,e){ $('#capbPlansMenu').popup('close'); $root.copyPlan(o); }"><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- ko if: $root.confirm -->
<div id="capbConfirm" data-role="popup" class="capbConfirmPopup" data-transition="fade" data-bind="with: $root.confirm">
    <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
    <!-- ko if: $data.question -->
    <p data-bind="text: question"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.item -->
    <p data-bind="text: item"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div class="capbBtns">
        <a href="#" class="capbBtn capbBtnCancel" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="capbBtn" data-bind="click: confirmed">Continue</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine on chrome, but when opening it in FF the popups are immediately shown as the page opens and just hangs at the top of the page (stacked on each other).

I inspected the popup container and i can see that on chrome it is given this class: `ui-popup-hidden` which sets its top/left properties to -9999 and essentially hiding it.

On FF i see it is getting the `ui-selectmenu-hidden` instead ,which has no effect.

Please help me, I've been banging my head on it for a few hours now.

Comment: same screen size on both browsers?

Comment: No, FF on smaller screen, but how is that related?

Comment: jQM is responsive to screen size. It dynamically changes styles of content according to screen size. What does the popup contain? or is it a select menu?

Comment: it is a simple popup, all popups should behave the same no matter the screen size. Specifically, they should all be hidden by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but clearing the FF cache helped! the problem is gone.